# "Cannot access a disposed context" when trying to access EF Core DbContext in Startup ExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 3.0 application. Within my Startup.cs `Configure` method, I'm handling unexpected errors and sending an email notification. It has worked perfectly.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IEmailService emailService)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(options =>
        {
            options.Run(
                async context =>
                {
                    var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (ex != null)
                    {
                        await emailService.SendErrorEmailAsync(context, ex);
                        context.Response.Redirect($"/Error/{context.Response.StatusCode}");
                    }
                });
        }
        );
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //...
}
```

I'd now like to improve it by including some information about the user. To do so, I tried the following:

```
private readonly MyApplicationContext _dbContext;
private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

public EmailService(MyApplicationContext dbContext, IServiceProvider services) {
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _services = services;
}

public async Task SendErrorEmailAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
{
    var _userService = _services.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
    var user = await _userService.GetCurrentUserAsync();

    //...build email, send, etc
}
```

`var _userService = _services.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();`  throws the following:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

As a workaround, I figured I could try calling the database directly instead of going through the `IUserService`:

```
public async Task SendErrorEmailAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
{
    User user = null;
    var isLoggedIn = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    if (isLoggedIn)
    {
        var idString = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        if (idString != null)
        {
            var userId = Guid.Parse(idString);
            user = await _dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Client).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId );
        }
    }

    //...build email, send email, etc
}
```

The line `user = await _dbContext ...` throws:

> Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

In researching this issue, the most common cause is returning an `async void` or forgetting to use `await`. The `Configure` method within `Startup.cs` is obviously a `void`, but I'm not sure what workaround there may be if that is in fact the issue.

I appreciate any input. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a design issue as, at the time of resolving and injecting the desired dependencies, they will be using the startup's service provider and not the request's service provider.

I would first suggest resolving the service via the current request's context in the delegate

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(options => {
            options.Run(
                async context => {
                    var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (ex != null) {
                        IEmailService emailService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IEmailService>();
                        await emailService.SendErrorEmailAsync(context, ex);
                        context.Response.Redirect($"/Error/{context.Response.StatusCode}");
                    }
                });
        });
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //...
}
```

Also refactor the service to avoid passing the service provider.

```
private readonly MyApplicationContext dbContext;
private readonly IUserService userService;

public EmailService(MyApplicationContext dbContext, IUserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
}

public async Task SendErrorEmailAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex) {
    var user = await userService.GetCurrentUserAsync();
    
    //...build email, send, etc
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Unfortunately I'm currently injecting `IEmailService` into `IUserService`. I recognize that's a smell, but refactoring it is a few items down on the to-do list. I'll give this a go now!

Comment: @Santi then I suggest you review you current design as that will cause problems with a cyclic dependency

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you! And yep, the services as they were laid out initially worked well and were entirely one-way relationships, but as I've expanded the application, it's clear they'll now require a quick refactor. I plan to address that shortly.